# cv2.imshow cause my jupyter notebook crash on MacOS

Tags: macos, opencv, jupyter-notebook

when i use the `cv2.imshow()` in jupyter notebook , I can't close the pic window ,and if i force quit it ,that'll make the kernel crash.

My configurations here:

```
MacOS : MoJava 10.14.3
python 3.6.8
openCV 3.4.2
```

Here s the code I use:

```
img=cv2.imread('24.jpg')
   cv2.imshow('imgae',img)
   cv2.waitKey(0)
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and then I've found a solution on overstackflow , that is:

```
import cv2


img=cv2.imread('24.jpg')
cv2.imshow('imgae',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

It will close the pic window immediately when u press any key, but still keep a process on my taskbar named `python`.
And also, I can't close it unless I force quit it.